# Gitlab start page does not start using docker compose on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have a problem with running the gitlab start page using the docker.

The error that the browser returns looks like this:

```
This site is unavailable The localhost server has rejected the connection.
Try these solutions:

Check your connection
Check the proxy server and firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
web:
   image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
   restart: always
   hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
   environment:
     GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
       external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
       # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
   ports:
     - '81:80'
     - '443:443'
     - '22:22'
   volumes:
     - 'C:\docker\gitlab\volumes\etc:/etc/gitlab'
     - 'C:\docker\gitlab\volumes\log:/var/log/gitlab'
     - 'C:\docker\gitlab\volumes\opt:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

I also added to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 gitlab.example.com
```

I tried to open the website using 127.0.0.1:81, gitlab.example.com:81, localhost:81.

docker-compose up -d show that everything is ok.

I'm asking for your help because I'm a beginner on this subject.

`docker container logs <container id>` -> https://pastebin.com/PuJ46haM

Edit:Any idea ?

Comment: can you use `docker container logs <container>` to look for errors?

Comment: I add logs but cant see nothing what could crush it